# Problem with building an angular docker image

Tags: angular, docker, npm

Upon building an angular docker image, I had this error after running `npm run build --prod`:

> executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build --prod]: exit code: 1

Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Are you able to post a bit more of the error message which is being output? It may point towards where the issue lies

Comment: "Exit code 1" is a pretty generic error message that just says "it didn't work".  There's probably more of the error before that which explains what actually went wrong.  Can you [edit] the question to include a more complete error message, along with a [mcve] showing enough code to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Try `npm run build -- --prod`

Answer (score 0):

Use this following docker code or share your docker code 
Get your `app-name` from the `package-lock.json` file of you angular project.

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build  --prod
# Stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/{app-name} /usr/share/nginx/html
```